# Let $~f:\mathbb R^2\times\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R~$ s.t. $~f(v,w)=w^{\text{T}}Av~.$ Specify the reason for each options.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}~.$$ Let $~f:\mathbb R^2\times\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R~$ be defined by $~f(v,w)=w^{\text{T}}Av~.$ **Which of the following statement(/s) is/are true (*specify the reason for each option*)?**

- there exists an eigen vector $~v~$ of $~A~$ such that $~Av~$ is perpendicular to $~v~$.
- for every $~v\in \mathbb R^2~$, there exists a non zero $~w\in \mathbb R^2~$ such that $~f(v,w)=0~$.
- the set $~\{v\in \mathbb R^2:f(v,v)=0\}~$ is a non zero subspace of $~\mathbb R^2~$.
- if $~v,~w\in \mathbb R^2~$ are non zero vectors such that $~f(v,v)=0=f(w,w)~$, then $~v~$ is a scalar multiple of $~w~$.
- none of the above.

Thanks for your time in advance.

---

**Edit:** I got an explanation to have the second option correct.

Let us consider $~v=\begin{pmatrix}
a \\
b
\end{pmatrix}~$and$~w=\begin{pmatrix}
c \\
d
\end{pmatrix}~$.

Then $~w^{\text{T}}Av=(c~~d)\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
a \\
b
\end{pmatrix}=ac-bd~$.

Now $~w^{\text{T}}Av=0\implies ac-bd=0\implies \dfrac{a}{b}=\dfrac{d}{c}~$

which implies for every $~v=\begin{pmatrix}
a \\
b
\end{pmatrix}~$, there exists $~w=\begin{pmatrix}
c \\
d
\end{pmatrix}~$ such that $~f(u,w)=ac-bd=0~$.

**Another Question:** Is it correct ? If not that what to do ?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?  What have you tried?  Do you have any guesses as to what the answer should be?

Comment: The answer here is that the second option is the only correct one.  See if you can come up with reasons to justify this.

Comment: I understand that the second option is the only correct option, but I have no idea how to start. Will you help me ? @Omnomnomnom

Comment: Even so, there's always [something to try](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933/81360); here's a way to get started.  For the first one, what do the eigenvectors of $A$ look like?  For these eigenvectors, is $Av$ perpendicular to $A$? For the third and fourth, which vectors $v$ solve the equation $f(v,v) = 0$?

Comment: I include my work, now comment on it @Omnomnomnom